# apply css to grandparent div when slide is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cycle2

I have a carousel on my [homepage](https://www.apis.de). When the third carousel appears, the carousel buttons `div class="rotator-controls"` move down due to the image taking space. My goal here is to keep this div the same height as the other 4. Which means that when the `<span>` (index 2) of the grandchild div `<div class="rotator-pagination">` is active, I apply the correct css to the `<div class="rotator-controls">` (e.g. bottom:60px). As the carousel is jQuery cycle 2, when the span is active it has the class `cycle-pager-active`.

I have tried using  domcontentloaded. i.e.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var span = document.querySelector("#homepage-rotator > div.banner.cycle-slide.cycle-slide-active > div > div.banner-content-area > div.rotator-controls > div.rotator-pagination").children[2];

if (jQuery(span).hasClass("cycle-pager-active")){
var grandPDiv = document.querySelector("div.rotator-controls");
grandPDiv.style.bottom = "-60px";
}
});
```

This does not work. But if I do this in the console, and wait for the 3rd carousel to be acitve, using `jQuery(span).hasClass("cycle-pager-active")` returns `true`. 
How do i apply css (to its grandparent element) only when the span element is active?

Comment: You can write this code inside a callback function of cycle 2 plugin. There are events which you use

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.banner-content-area {
    min-height: 440px;
}
```

if not work then add min-height: 440px!important;

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly:

```
.banner-content-area {
    min-height: 440px;
}
```